# Can you use "that" in a non-defining relative clause?

Tags: relative-clauses

Two examples:

- Setting off fireworks is a *long* tradition **that** has existed for centuries.
- These days, we buy *more and more* things **that** we don't need.

According to the (simplified) rules, we can check if a relative clause is defining or not by leaving it out of the sentence and see if the sentence still makes sense. In the above sentences, I can leave out the second part of the sentence and still have a complete sentence, or at least, I think so. Nevertheless, using "that" somehow sounds okay to me...
Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: Preliminary point: non-defining _that_ relatives are not normally permitted in Standard English, so your examples are in fact defining relatives. It's true that if you drop the r/c the sentence would still make sense, but that's not the point. Take your second example: dropping the r/c would change the meaning since it defines which specific "things" are being referred to. The claim is not that we're buying more and more things these days, but we're buying more and more things that we don't need. We may be buying other things that are needed.

Comment: Your premise, should we leave out the relative clause and the sentence still make sense, the clause was non-defining is incorrect. The sentence still makes sense, but, if you are careful, you will see its meaning changes. The noun used to encompass fewer things than it does after leaving out the clause: *the clause was essential to convey the entire meaning*.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments - it makes it clear that I misinterpreted the rule.